Issue with Tooltip Not Appearing on Tab Navigation in Chrome/Firefox but Working in Edge
I'm encountering an issue with tooltips in our product across different browsers. Here's the scenario:
When hovering over an element with the mouse (which has a tooltip) on Edge and Chrome, the tooltip appears as expected.
We are currently working on improving accessibility, and part of that involves ensuring tooltips are visible when navigating via the Tab key.
Issue:

On Edge, when I navigate using the Tab key and focus on a
button/element, the tooltip appears as expected.
However, on Chrome and Firefox, the tooltip does not appear when I focus on the same
elements using the Tab key.

Details:

The tooltips are implemented using the title attribute, which is
passed as a prop to the component.
This behavior is consistent across different elements in our product.

I'm trying to understand:

Why is this behavior different between Edge and Chrome/Firefox?
Is there any known accessibility-related difference or
browser-specific handling of tooltips that could be causing this?
Are there any recommended fixes or workarounds for making tooltips
accessible consistently across browsers when using keyboard
navigation?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
